# sonarqube branch coverage shows too many options for asserts

Tags: java, sonarqube

im using the latest sonarqube to analyse a java project. in this project i have a simple Range class with 2 long attributes - start and end. when looking at the coverage data for the class i see this:

[image: sonarqube coverage for asserts]

basically it means i have 114 different tests passing through this constructor. i also have tests verifying each and every assert there (so a test with a negative start, another with negative end, a third with start before end etc).

and yet sonarqube thinks there are uncovered branches. what are the 4 branches in `assert start >= 0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not related to SonarQube because SonarQube just reads and processes the report generated by your code coverage tool. If you have a look at the byte code, the "assert" keyword is likely to generate some extra code, thus some extra branches. If your coverage tool is JaCoCo, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jacoco/kjhbX_ExrAA for example.

Comment: thanks for the helpful link. so there's basically nothing i can do abotu it, as jacoc havent implemented this filtering?

Comment: Correct, there's nothing you can do about it for now. Feel free to ping guys working on JaCoCo.